# Configure APNS on Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

I'm trying to migrate from Parse.com service to a self-hosted Parse Server, and it's been a bit difficult.

Basically I set up my server like this:

1. Run `$ npm install -g parse-server`
2. Set env vars (PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI, PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY, PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID)
3. Run `$ parse-server`

Everything is up and running, and I also setup a machine running parse-dashboard in a very similar way.

I had already synced the database and had no problems with it.

The problem is that when I try to send a push notification, I get the message:

> Missing push configuration

I believe that's connected to the APNS settings. In Parse.com dashboard we can add the APNS certificates, but on the self hosted dashboard there is no such option (or I couldn't find it).

What am I missing? How do I set theses things up?

Comment: The parse-server documentation covers setting up apns https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-Server/wiki/Push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that running parse-server without the recommended Express wrapper does not give me full control of everything I needed to configure the application.

I created an Express app, started the serving using the guide @thailey01 suggested and now it works.